# How run excel command lines from batch file

Tags: excel, powershell, batch-file, command-line, automation

I need to automate an excel file creation and formatting from file explorer. I've wrote the code to run directly in PowerShell, but I want to make it just executing a batch file (.bat). Here are a sample lines:

```
$excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application
$excel.visible = $true
$workbook = $excel.workbooks.Add()
$sheet = $workbook.worksheets.item(1)
$r = 64; $g = 64; $b = 64;
$rgb = $r + ($g * 256) + ($b * 256 * 256);
$sheet.name = 'NOTAS'
$sheet.Range("A:A").ColumnWidth = 3; $sheet.Range("B:B").ColumnWidth = 12; $sheet.Range("C:C").ColumnWidth = 100; $sheet.Range("D:D").ColumnWidth = 12; 
$sheet.Range("1:1").RowHeight = 50; $sheet.Range("2:1000").RowHeight = 20; 
...
```

Seems that I need to write them in another way, as once I execute the .bat file nothing happens. I suspect this is not the proper way to code in .bat files.

Please, notice that I DO NOT NEED a VBA option, only .bat solutions.

I appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: Batch isn't able to do anything like that. Especially, batch can't interact with Excel at all.

Comment: Ok, so can I run these lines in a PowerShell script? What I need is a single file that creates a project folder structure and add an excel file inside one of the subfolders, no matter where the main folder is located. Do you have any idea or advice?

Comment: What is stopping you from running the PowerShell `-File` from a batch file? Or even embedding the PowerShell content directly into the batch file and running it as a PowerShell `-Command` from that same batch file? We aren't here to write those for you though, and both ideasthave been covered on this site multiple times before. Please use the search facility, at the top of the page, to locate and adapt one yourself. Thank you.

Comment: If you want something from the command line, why not use vbscript instead?

Answer (score 0):

Batch files cannot run PowerShell code. You can, however, use a batch file to run the script using PowerShell with the `-File` parameter.

Ensure your PowerShell script is saved with a `.ps1` extension. Then write a batch script with the following:

```
start powershell.exe -file PSScript.ps1
```

Replace the file name with whatever you named your script.